# The development server provided with django, ./manage.py runserver, no longer updating when changing the views.py code

Tags: python, django, web, server

I am using a virtual machine and the development server provided with django, ./manage.py runserver. Which, was working wonderfully. But now when I run the command ./manage.py runserver, it no longer executes with the most updated code (views.py). I have restarted the virtual machine, the server, etc. But I cannot get it to work.

Most answers on stack overflow regarding this topic state that if you're using ./manage.py runserver, you shouldn't run into this problem. So I'm not sure how else I should continue to solve the issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: usually this happens when settings.DEBUG is False, or when the code you modify is in a django app which is not added to setting.INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: debug is set to true and my app is in installed_apps. in settings.py